# Topological entropy and periodic sequences of a subshift

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

Let $\Sigma$ be a two-sided subshift on a finite alphabet $A$. Let $\Sigma_n$ denote all words $x_{-n}\dots x_n\in A^{2n+1}$ such that $(x_k)_{-\infty}^\infty \in \Sigma$ for some $x_k, |k|>n$.

Its topological entropy is defined as follows:
$$
h(\Sigma) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log \#\Sigma_n}{2n+1}.
$$
Now let $Per_n$ denote all periodic sequences in $\Sigma$ of period $n$. Assume
$$
\widetilde h(\Sigma) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log \#Per_n}{n}=0.
$$

**Question.** I need sufficient conditions for $h(\Sigma)=0$. It is known to hold for the sofic subshifts (Lind & Marcus, Exercise 4.4.3) but in my examples they are not sofic. Nor are they transitive.

Comment: If I'm correct, there are Toeplitz subshifts that are minimal (so $\tilde{h}=0$) and have positive topological entropy.

Comment: There is an explicit construction due to Furstenberg (and Katznelson-Hahn) of subshift which is uniquely ergodic and with positive entropy.

Comment: Oh I'm sure there are examples like that. What I need some property which ensures this does not happen. Specification works, for instance, but what if my subshift is not even transitive, for instance?

Comment: Probably $\tilde{h}=0\Rightarrow h=0$ true and easy for a subshift of finite type, but I don't know if it's of interest for you.

Comment: It is indeed true since any SFT has *weak specification property*: there exists $k\ge0$ such that if $u$ and $v$ are in the language of our subshift, then there exists a word $w$ of length $\le k$ such that $uwv$ is in the same language. In other words, it's transitive with ``bridges'' of bounded length.

Comment: I believe you want $Per_n$ to be the set of periodic points with period $2n+1$.  Also, is it clear that the limit in $\tilde{h}(\Sigma)$ always exists?

Comment: For sofic shifts (not necessarily irreducible), there is the equality $h(\Sigma)=\tilde{h}(\Sigma)$ as long as the limit in $\tilde{h}(\Sigma)$ exists.  This is exercise 4.4.3 of the book of Lind and Marcus.

Comment: Algernon - You're right, the existence of the limit is an extra assumption, Let's make it, then.

Comment: But the existence of the limit seems quite restrictive.  For instance, the limit fails to exist for an SFT with period $d\geq 2$.  You may want to replace the limit with limsup as Lind & Marcus do.  By the way, you either need to change the definition of $Per_n$ or replace $2n+1$ in the denominator with $n$.

Comment: Can you say anything more about your class of examples?  There are non-uniform specification properties that do not imply transitivity; for example, almost specification (Pfister & Sullivan's "approximate product" property), or the non-uniform "specification up to obstructions with small entropy" that Dan Thompson and I introduced (Israel J., 2012).  The latter property implies that periodic points grow with rate equal to topological entropy.  I don't know whether almost specification implies that, would need to think about it more.  These may not be relevant to your examples though...

Comment: Vaughn, here's a toy example. Let $t$ be the Thue-Morse constant, i.e., its binary expansion is $0110 1001 1001 0110\dots$. Consider the open map which is the doubling map with the hole $(t,1-t)$. Here any sequence is of the form $t_1^{k_1}t_2^{k_2}\dots$, where $t_k$ is the prefix of the Thue-Morse sequence of length $2^k$ and $k_j\ge0$ and may equal $\infty$. The only admissible cycles are $t_k^\infty$, which easily implies $\tilde h=0$. We also have $h=0$, which follows from the description of the subshift. Clearly, $t_k$ cannot be followed by $t_j$ with $j<k$, so it's not transitive.

Comment: Every minimal ${\bf Z} $-action on a Cantor set is (strongly) orbit equivalent to a (minimal) subshift of entropy zero. Is this of interest?

Comment: David, I am interested in subshifts where periodic orbits do exist. Thus, they cannot be minimal.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, any piecewise expanding interval map with a hole (such as your example with the Thue-Morse constant) can be modeled as a factor of a countable-state Markov shift by using the Hofbauer tower, and then the spectral decomposition of such shifts would give a way to approach the relationship between periodic points and topological entropy, even when the shift is not transitive.  I haven't thought through the details though...

Comment: Vaughn, thanks. I guess the bottom line is that there is no general result which I could use straight away. Personally I think this is a very natural question in a general setting, since it is usually easier to describe the cycles than all admissible sequences. Hopefully, such general results will be proved in the near future!